# 2D String search in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PhoneNumbers
{
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String phoneList[][] =

    {
      {"Harrison, Rose: ", "James, Jean: ", "Smith, William: ", "Smith, Brad: "},

      {"415-555-2234", "415-555-9098", "415-555-1785", "415-555-9224"}
    };


    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(phoneList)); //this line is to make sure the 2D arrays work

    String input;

    System.out.print("Enter the first few letters of a last name to search for: ");
    input = scan.nextLine();

    int match = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < phoneList.length; i++)
    {
      if(phoneList[i].indexOf(input))
      {
        System.out.println(phoneList[i]);
        match = i;
        break;
      }
      else
        System.out.println("There is no match.");
    }    


  }
}
```

My goal is:
I have a 2D array, i got name in one and the phone number in another.
I am trying to allow user to enter first few letters of a last name and do a search that and display the matching search along with the phone number(this would be my next challenge).

Thank you,

Comment: And what does not work / what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer :

```
 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int refNumber=-1;

        String phoneList[][] =

            {
              {"Harrison, Rose: ", "James, Jean: ", "Smith, William: ", "Smith, Brad: "},

              {"415-555-2234", "415-555-9098", "415-555-1785", "415-555-9224"}
            };


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter String to be searched ->");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        //System.out.println(input);

        for (int i=0; i<phoneList[0].length; i++) {
            if (phoneList[0][i].contains(input)) {
                refNumber = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Name ->"+phoneList[0][refNumber]);
        System.out.println("Phone No ->"+phoneList[1][refNumber]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary (e.g. trie tree) for all the names you have. While creating/updating your search dictionary, at each node, keep an integer array which gives you the list of index of all the matching names. As the user provides input, you can keep on refining the result at runtime, and when he selects any one of the provided suggestions, you'll have the index to it.
Rest is simple, using that index, display the phone number of the selected person.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to match the beginning of the input String:

```
for(int x=0; x<phoneList[1].length; x++)
    if(phoneList[0][x].toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase()))
        System.out.println("Numbers which matched: " + phoneList[1][x]);
```

**Program output:**

```
//Using "smith" as input:    
Numbers which matched: 415-555-1785
Numbers which matched: 415-555-9224
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some refactoring:

using a Map: name => phone

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String phoneList[][] =

    {
      {"Harrison, Rose: ", "James, Jean: ", "Smith, William: ", "Smith, Brad: "},

      {"415-555-2234", "415-555-9098", "415-555-1785", "415-555-9224"}
    };

    // Make a Map
    Map<String,String> mss=new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < phoneList.length; i++)
        mss.put(phoneList[0][i], phoneList[1][i]) ;

    String input;

    System.out.print("Enter the first few letters of a last name to search for: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    input = scan.nextLine();

    String match="";

    for (String name: mss.keySet())
        if (name.startsWith(input))
            {
            System.out.println("NAME:"+name+ " PHONE:"+mss.get(name));
            match=name;
            break;
            }

    if (match.equals(""))
        System.out.println("There is no match.");
}
```